# STM32 USB audio device - headset - can`t init second interface

Tags: audio, usb, stm32f4discovery

Currently I`m trying to create some kind of USB headset on STM32F407 - device, that able to play audio stream from host and send audio samples, received from mic.

USB Audio device topology looks like this(sorry for bad quality):
[topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmTGP.png)

I`m using two endpoints here. As a result I describe two interface in USB descriptor.

Descriptors looks like this:

```
static uint8_t usbd_audio_CfgDesc[AUDIO_CONFIG_DESC_SIZE] =
{
  /* Configuration 1 */
  0x09,                                 /* bLength */
  USB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,    /* bDescriptorType */
  LOBYTE(AUDIO_CONFIG_DESC_SIZE),       /* wTotalLength  183 bytes*/
  HIBYTE(AUDIO_CONFIG_DESC_SIZE),      
  0x03,                                 /* bNumInterfaces */
  0x01,                                 /* bConfigurationValue */
  0x00,                                 /* iConfiguration */
  0xC0,                                 /* bmAttributes  BUS Powred*/
  0x32,                                 /* bMaxPower = 100 mA*/
  /* 09 byte*/
  
  /* USB Headset Standard interface descriptor */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,            /* bLength */
  USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,        /* bDescriptorType */
  0x00,                                 /* bInterfaceNumber */
  0x00,                                 /* bAlternateSetting */
  0x00,                                 /* bNumEndpoints */
  USB_DEVICE_CLASS_AUDIO,               /* bInterfaceClass */
  AUDIO_SUBCLASS_AUDIOCONTROL,          /* bInterfaceSubClass */
  AUDIO_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED,             /* bInterfaceProtocol */
  0x00,                                 /* iInterface */
  /* 09 byte*/
  
  /* USB Headset Class-specific AC Interface Descriptor */
  0x0A,                                 /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_HEADER,                 /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x00,          /* 1.00 */             /* bcdADC */
  0x01,
  0x3C,                                 /* wTotalLength = 60*/
  0x00,
  0x02,                                 /* bInCollection */
  0x01,                                 /* baInterfaceNr(1) - OUT */
  0x02,                                 /* baInterfaceNr(2) - IN */
  /* 10 byte*/
  
  /* USB Microphone Input Terminal Descriptor */
  AUDIO_INPUT_TERMINAL_DESC_SIZE,       /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_INPUT_TERMINAL,         /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x01,                                 /* bTerminalID */
  0x01,                                 /* wTerminalType MICROPHONE   0x0201 */
  0x02,
  0x00,                                 /* bAssocTerminal */
  0x01,                                 /* bNrChannels */
  0x00,                                 /* wChannelConfig 0x0000  Mono */
  0x00,
  0x00,                                 /* iChannelNames */
  0x00,                                 /* iTerminal */
  /* 12 byte*/
  
  /*USB Microphone Output Terminal Descriptor */
  0x09,      /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_OUTPUT_TERMINAL,        /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x02,                                 /* bTerminalID */
  0x01,                                 /* wTerminalType  USB_STREAMING 0x0101*/
  0x01,
  0x00,                                 /* bAssocTerminal */
  0x01,                                 /* bSourceID */
  0x00,                                 /* iTerminal */
  /* 09 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Input Terminal Descriptor */
  AUDIO_INPUT_TERMINAL_DESC_SIZE,       /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_INPUT_TERMINAL,         /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x05,                                 /* bTerminalID */
  0x01,                                 /* wTerminalType AUDIO_TERMINAL_USB_STREAMING   0x0101 */
  0x01,
  0x00,                                 /* bAssocTerminal */
  0x01,                                 /* bNrChannels */
  0x00,                                 /* wChannelConfig 0x0000  Mono */
  0x00,
  0x00,                                 /* iChannelNames */
  0x00,                                 /* iTerminal */
  /* 12 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Audio Feature Unit Descriptor */
  0x09,                                 /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_FEATURE_UNIT,           /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  AUDIO_OUT_FEATURE_UNIT_ID,            /* bUnitID */
  0x05,                                 /* bSourceID */
  0x01,                                 /* bControlSize */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_MUTE,                   /* bmaControls(0) */
  0x00,                                 /* bmaControls(1) */
  0x00,                                 /* iTerminal */
  /* 09 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Output Terminal Descriptor */
  0x09,                                 /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_CONTROL_OUTPUT_TERMINAL,        /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x03,                                 /* bTerminalID */
  0x01,                                 /* wTerminalType  0x0301*/
  0x03,
  0x00,                                 /* bAssocTerminal */
  0x04,                                 /* bSourceID */
  0x00,                                 /* iTerminal */
  /* 09 byte*/

  /* USB Speaker Standard AS Interface Descriptor - Audio Streaming Zero Bandwith */
  /* Interface 1, Alternate Setting 0                                             */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,  /* bLength */
  USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,        /* bDescriptorType */
  0x01,                                 /* bInterfaceNumber */
  0x00,                                 /* bAlternateSetting */
  0x00,                                 /* bNumEndpoints */
  USB_DEVICE_CLASS_AUDIO,               /* bInterfaceClass */
  AUDIO_SUBCLASS_AUDIOSTREAMING,        /* bInterfaceSubClass */
  AUDIO_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED,             /* bInterfaceProtocol */
  0x00,                                 /* iInterface */
  /* 09 byte*/
  
  /* USB Speaker Standard AS Interface Descriptor - Audio Streaming Operational */
  /* Interface 1, Alternate Setting 1                                           */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,            /* bLength */
  USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,        /* bDescriptorType */
  0x01,                                 /* bInterfaceNumber */
  0x01,                                 /* bAlternateSetting */
  0x01,                                 /* bNumEndpoints */
  USB_DEVICE_CLASS_AUDIO,               /* bInterfaceClass */
  AUDIO_SUBCLASS_AUDIOSTREAMING,        /* bInterfaceSubClass */
  AUDIO_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED,             /* bInterfaceProtocol */
  0x00,                                 /* iInterface */
  /* 09 byte*/
  
  /* USB Speaker Audio Streaming Interface Descriptor */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,  /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_GENERAL,              /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x05,                                 /* bTerminalLink */
  0x01,                                 /* bDelay */
  0x01,                                 /* wFormatTag AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM  0x0001*/
  0x00,
  /* 07 byte*/
  
  /* USB Speaker Audio Type III Format Interface Descriptor */
  0x0B,                                 /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_FORMAT_TYPE,          /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  AUDIO_FORMAT_TYPE_III,                /* bFormatType */ 
  0x02,                                 /* bNrChannels */
  0x02,                                 /* bSubFrameSize :  2 Bytes per frame (16bits) */
  16,                                   /* bBitResolution (16-bits per sample) */ 
  0x01,                                 /* bSamFreqType only one frequency supported */ 
  SAMPLE_FREQ(USBD_AUDIO_FREQ),         /* Audio sampling frequency coded on 3 bytes */
  /* 11 byte*/
  
  /* Endpoint 1 - Standard Descriptor */
  AUDIO_STANDARD_ENDPOINT_DESC_SIZE,    /* bLength */
  USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,         /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_OUT_EP,                         /* bEndpointAddress 1 out endpoint*/
  USB_ENDPOINT_TYPE_ISOCHRONOUS,        /* bmAttributes */
  AUDIO_PACKET_SZE(USBD_AUDIO_FREQ, 2), /* wMaxPacketSize in Bytes (Freq(Samples)*2(Stereo)*2(HalfWord)) */
  0x01,                                 /* bInterval */
  0x00,                                 /* bRefresh */
  0x00,                                 /* bSynchAddress */
  /* 09 byte*/
  
  /* Endpoint - Audio Streaming Descriptor*/
  AUDIO_STREAMING_ENDPOINT_DESC_SIZE,   /* bLength */
  AUDIO_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,       /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_ENDPOINT_GENERAL,               /* bDescriptor */
  0x00,                                 /* bmAttributes */
  0x00,                                 /* bLockDelayUnits */
  0x00,                                 /* wLockDelay */
  0x00,
  /* 07 byte*/
  
  /* USB Microphone Standard AS Interface Descriptor - Audio Streaming Zero Bandwith */
  /* Interface 2, Alternate Setting 0                                             */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,  /* bLength */
  USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,        /* bDescriptorType */
  0x02,                                 /* bInterfaceNumber */
  0x00,                                 /* bAlternateSetting */
  0x00,                                 /* bNumEndpoints */
  USB_DEVICE_CLASS_AUDIO,               /* bInterfaceClass */
  AUDIO_SUBCLASS_AUDIOSTREAMING,        /* bInterfaceSubClass */
  AUDIO_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED,             /* bInterfaceProtocol */
  0x00,                                 /* iInterface */
  /* 09 byte*/
  
  /* USB Microphone Standard AS Interface Descriptor - Audio Streaming Operational */
  /* Interface 2, Alternate Setting 1                                           */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,  /* bLength */
  USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,        /* bDescriptorType */
  0x02,                                 /* bInterfaceNumber */
  0x01,                                 /* bAlternateSetting */
  0x01,                                 /* bNumEndpoints */
  USB_DEVICE_CLASS_AUDIO,               /* bInterfaceClass */
  AUDIO_SUBCLASS_AUDIOSTREAMING,        /* bInterfaceSubClass */
  AUDIO_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED,             /* bInterfaceProtocol */
  0x00,                                 /* iInterface */
  /* 09 byte*/
  
  /* USB Microphone Audio Streaming Interface Descriptor */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,  /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_GENERAL,              /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  0x02,                                 /* bTerminalLink */
  0x01,                                 /* bDelay */
  0x01,                                 /* wFormatTag AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM  0x0001*/
  0x00,
  /* 07 byte*/
  
  /* USB Microphone Type I Format Interface Descriptor */
  0x0B,                                 /* bLength */
  AUDIO_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_STREAMING_FORMAT_TYPE,          /* bDescriptorSubtype */
  AUDIO_FORMAT_TYPE_I,                /* bFormatType */ 
  0x01,                                 /* bNrChannels */
  0x02,                                 /* bSubFrameSize :  2 Bytes per frame (16bits) */
  16,                                   /* bBitResolution (16-bits per sample) */ 
  0x01,                                 /* bSamFreqType only one frequency supported */ 
  SAMPLE_FREQ(USBD_IN_FREQ),         /* Audio sampling frequency coded on 3 bytes */
  /* 11 byte*/
  
  /* Endpoint 1 - Standard Descriptor */
  AUDIO_STANDARD_ENDPOINT_DESC_SIZE,    /* bLength */
  USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,         /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_IN_EP,                         /* bEndpointAddress 1 out endpoint*/
  USB_ENDPOINT_TYPE_ISOCHRONOUS,        /* bmAttributes */
  AUDIO_PACKET_SZE(USBD_IN_FREQ, 1),    /* wMaxPacketSize in Bytes (Freq(Samples)*2(Stereo)*2(HalfWord)) */
  0x01,                                 /* bInterval */
  0x00,                                 /* bRefresh */
  0x00,                                 /* bSynchAddress */
  /* 09 byte*/
  
  /* Endpoint - Audio Microphone Descriptor*/
  AUDIO_STREAMING_ENDPOINT_DESC_SIZE,   /* bLength */
  AUDIO_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,       /* bDescriptorType */
  AUDIO_ENDPOINT_GENERAL,               /* bDescriptor */
  0x00,                                 /* bmAttributes */
  0x00,                                 /* bLockDelayUnits */
  0x00,                                 /* wLockDelay */
  0x00,
  /* 07 byte*/
} ;
```

When I`m connecting this device to host, it seems that host successfully enumerate it.

Logs of the host (Linux OS):

```
[12221.001223] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5730, bcdDevice= 2.00
[12221.001246] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[12221.001248] usb 3-4: Product: STM32 AUDIO Streaming in FS Mode
[12221.001250] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[12221.001252] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 347E37553434
[12221.037373] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[12221.073785] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

This newly connected device is able to play audio stream, that it receive from host. But when I`m trying to record something, I saw in logs following message:

```
[12758.466715] usb 3-4: 2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-32)
[12758.466894] usb 3-4: 2:0: usb_set_interface failed (-32)
[12758.826837] usb 3-4: 2:0: usb_set_interface failed (-32)
[12758.827398] usb 3-4: 2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-32)
```

Seems, that host is fail to set up second interface - interface for audio stream from device mic to host.

When I`ve tried to sniff USB packet, using Wireshark, I saw following:

1. Device successfully send all his descriptors.
2. Host tried to set different alt settings for interface 1 - all request finished with success.
3. Host tried to do same operation with interface 2 - it failed with error "broken pipe"

Set interface 1. Request:

```
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 3.8.0]
    URB id: 0xffff8ce44b991e40
    URB type: URB_SUBMIT ('S')
    URB transfer type: URB_CONTROL (0x02)
    Endpoint: 0x00, Direction: OUT
    Device: 8
    URB bus id: 3
    Device setup request: relevant (0)
    Data: present (0)
    URB sec: 1645475418
    URB usec: 822919
    URB status: Operation now in progress (-EINPROGRESS) (-115)
    URB length [bytes]: 0
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Response in: 32]
    Interval: 0
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000000
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
Setup Data
    bmRequestType: 0x01
    bRequest: SET INTERFACE (11)
    bAlternateSetting: 0
    wInterface: 1
    wLength: 0
```

Set interface 1. Response:

```
USB URB
    [Source: 3.8.0]
    [Destination: host]
    URB id: 0xffff8ce44b991e40
    URB type: URB_COMPLETE ('C')
    URB transfer type: URB_CONTROL (0x02)
    Endpoint: 0x00, Direction: OUT
    Device: 8
    URB bus id: 3
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: not present ('>')
    URB sec: 1645475418
    URB usec: 822989
    URB status: Success (0)
    URB length [bytes]: 0
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Request in: 31]
    [Time from request: 0.000070000 seconds]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 0
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000000
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
```

Set interface 2. Request:

```
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 3.8.0]
    URB id: 0xffff8ce63c2d2840
    URB type: URB_SUBMIT ('S')
    URB transfer type: URB_CONTROL (0x02)
    Endpoint: 0x00, Direction: OUT
    Device: 8
    URB bus id: 3
    Device setup request: relevant (0)
    Data: present (0)
    URB sec: 1645475418
    URB usec: 823040
    URB status: Operation now in progress (-EINPROGRESS) (-115)
    URB length [bytes]: 0
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Response in: 34]
    Interval: 0
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000000
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
Setup Data
    bmRequestType: 0x01
    bRequest: SET INTERFACE (11)
    bAlternateSetting: 0
    wInterface: 2
    wLength: 0
```

Set interface 2. Response:

```
USB URB
    [Source: 3.8.0]
    [Destination: host]
    URB id: 0xffff8ce63c2d2840
    URB type: URB_COMPLETE ('C')
    URB transfer type: URB_CONTROL (0x02)
    Endpoint: 0x00, Direction: OUT
    Device: 8
    URB bus id: 3
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: not present ('>')
    URB sec: 1645475418
    URB usec: 823198
    URB status: Broken pipe (-EPIPE) (-32)
    URB length [bytes]: 0
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Request in: 33]
    [Time from request: 0.000158000 seconds]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 0
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000000
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
```

I put whole wireshark .cap file in my [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17qxIqzuGU8mQEHYIWouLL_NFRD7C7aUN/view?usp=sharing) disk:

Code for my overall project you can find in my [github](https://github.com/ancher-bohdan/stm32_usb_interface/tree/task/usb_headset) (branch - task/usb_headset)

I was tried to set sampling frequency for both audio stream to 48 kHz. According to the descriptors above audio stream from host - 48kHz, stereo; audio stream to host - 16kHz, mono. Same error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok. It seems that I`ve fixed problem with -EPIPE(-32) error during initialization of second interface. It was problem in configuration of my USB stack in device.

Comment: But now I have new problem - device cant play music from host and record my voice from mic simultaneously. If I`m trying to record something from mic during music is playing from host - play process is stopped and recording process is starting.

I suspect. that there is a serious bug in my code. But if someone see some obvious error in descriptor, please tell me

Answer (score 2):

I`ve fixed a new problem too.

There was an error in my USB TX FIFO size configuration.

If anybody interested, you can see my code here - https://github.com/ancher-bohdan/stm32_usb_interface